# Is Firebase Storage Bucket insecure when rules are empty?

Tags: firebase-storage, firebase-security

I recently realized that my rules for the storage buckets in firebase are empty.
Like completely empty.
Does that mean than anyone has access to the buckets?

And if yes, how do I update the rules for the **cloud function bucket** specifically so that the functions keep working and I can still deploy new functions via the CLI?

I updated the storage bucket already
but I am waiting to update the rules for the "cloud functions" and "artifacts" buckets as I don't know what will happen if I secure them.

I looked everywhere in the docs but couldn't find anything specific.